# ShapeShift.com Phishing - I lost 67 Ethereum - What do I do?

Tags: ether, myetherwallet, shapeshift, phishing

I fell for the shapeshift.com scam which provide a false ETh wallet address and they basically steal your ETH. The real website is shapeshift.io

Here is more information on the transaction:

1. https://etherscan.io/address/0x3853ba76ec6ae97818e2d0e0839c9eda6c396690
   My transaction is block 4691646 where my coinbase account sent 66.679 ETH to the phishing account from shapeshift.com and not shapeshift.io.

How can I get my ETH back? WHo do I talk to? Please help.

Comment: For anyone else reading this, I'd recommend installing either the EtherAddressLookup, MyEtherWallet or MetaMask browser plugin (or even all 3, just to be safe). These include a tool that will check any URL for known phishing/scam sites, and warn/redirect as appropriate.

Comment: Yeah Please follow instructions and be very careful. I'm still trying to figure out what to do. Pretty hopeless @RichardHorrocks

Answer (score 0):

Both domain redirects to a single `tld`.

> Location: https://shapeshift.io/

[image: shapeshift]

Comment: What does this mean? What should I even do in this situation? @niksmac

Comment: @AkhilK means, both the domain are authentic.